# Display all values as Dropdown on focus

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

This is my code. When I start typing, it filters the list.

I want to display all the values as drop down on focus of the input text.

If the user start typing, then I want filtering. If the user just focus and didn't type anything, I want to show all the values as drop down.

How can I do this ?

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.selected = undefined;
  $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Dakota', 'North Carolina', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];
});
```

```
<h4>Search State</h4>
<pre>Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" data-typeahead-editable="false" data-ng-model="selected" data-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
```

[Plunker DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/SjASFL8BkKdjLRxUlGVA?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no built in function for this feature.

But you can work around this. Read more here

[Angular JS - Automatically focus input and show typeahead dropdown - ui.bootstrap.typeahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764802/angular-js-automatically-focus-input-and-show-typeahead-dropdown-ui-bootstra)

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: This should be the best answer for this question