# angularui bootstrap typeahead- prepopulate dropdown list onfocus

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I am using angularui bootstrap [typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) module for my project.

I am unable to pre-populate the drop-down with predefined value.
Whenever user click on input text of typeahead, it should automatically show the typeahead suggestion dropdown(from a static JSON).

Whenever user starts typing, then the behaviour should be normal.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24767467/1348550) solution but unfortunately it stopped working when I upgraded my angularjs to version  1.3

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I essentially accomplished this by making a custom directive and making a minor modification to the ui bootstrap typeahead code. You have to trick the typeahead into thinking someone has typed something in it.  I placed a little pulldown arrow to the right of the field so essentially it looked like a pulldown and clicking on that arrow would show ALL choices. You should be able to do it using onfocus.
Basically find the code in the bootstrap typeahead that binds to the key events and I changed it to check for a keydown event of 40

```
           if(scope.matches.length === 0 && evt.which === 40) {  // Added            
         //   COMMENT OUT  modelCtrl.$setViewValue(modelCtrl.$viewValue);
                          modelCtrl.$setViewValue('');  // Added
            }
```

You'll also need to make sure the typeaheadMinLength is set to 0.  Note in the code above it checks for the case of the user NOT having typed anything AND the special keydown event that I trigger. You should be able to change this to trigger on onfocus. I copied the bootstrap typeahead to mytypeahead.js and then modified it as above, along with a few other minor mods that you may or may not need depending on if the field is "required" or not.