# AngularJS Typeahead To Always Show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I am using the AngularJS `typeahead` directive to iterate over an array of objects which has been populated before-hand by an API, so that the `typeahead` is pulling all information from memory.

**I would like that when the `input` gains `focus`, the `typeahead` is shown with all available results, even when there is no `value` in the `input`.**

I found [this simple JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfz6S/17/) for a `typeahead` that we can use to test with.

I've tried using:

```
<input typeahead-min-length="0" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="query" typeahead="warehouse.info for warehouse in warehouses | filter:$viewValue" typeahead-on-select="selectedWarehouse = $item;" ng-keypress="fetchWarehouses();"/>
```

..thinking that the attribute `typeahead-min-length="0"` could accomplish this, but it didn't.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular JS - Automatically focus input and show typeahead dropdown - ui.bootstrap.typeahead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764802/angular-js-automatically-focus-input-and-show-typeahead-dropdown-ui-bootstra)

Comment: @BettySt yes, I believe you are right. Thank you for pointing out the answer. Sorry for the duplicate.