# Focus on input does not always call keyboard for ios angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, angular, focus

I am using angular 1 and `md-autocomplete`

```
      <md-autocomplete
            md-autofocus="true"
            md-autoselect="true"
            md-select-on-match="false"
            md-search-text-change="$ctrl.searchTextChange($ctrl.searchText)"
            md-search-text="$ctrl.searchText"
            md-items="item in $ctrl.performQuery($ctrl.searchText)"
            md-item-text="item.name"
            md-no-cache="true"
            md-min-length="0"
            placeholder="{{'core.common.filter.results' | translate}}"
            md-selected-item-change="$ctrl.onItemChange()"
            ng-readonly="$ctrl.isReadOnly">
```

Here how my autocomplete is defined

```
        setFocus(){
             setTimeout(() => {
                 this.$element.find('md-autocomplete').find('input').focus()
        },0)
    }
```

From another method I call `setFocus()` func

for desktop and android everything works correctly. Both necessary functionality are called: autocomplete selectors and keyboard(for mobile)

I also debugged and found that correct input is focused

but the problem is that focus on input does not call keyboard on ios every time, it can happen randomly. in this time autocomplete suggestions are shown every time

also tried to use `querySelectorAll` and `querySelector` the same problem

```
document.querySelectorAll('md-autocomplete > md-autocomplete-wrap > input')[0].focus()
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XzPGYv  same problem reproduced even in android

Comment: seem like it is angular issue . but must to be fixed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24767467/4342514 you can find link in this answer where it is also reproduced